# Downloading PHP HTML content as PDF in CodeIgniter not displaying properly

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

I have a CodeIgniter website which has a view page like the following:

[image]

So now I want to download the page as PDF, so I used tcpdf and created a controller function and a view like below:

```php
function downloadpdf() {
    $this->load->library('Pdf');
    $id = $this->uri->segment('3');
    $data['result'] = $this->excel_import_model->printsingle($id);
    $this->load->view('pdfreport', $data);
}
```

```php
<?php
    $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $title = "PDF Report";
    $obj_pdf->SetTitle($title);
    $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, $title, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
    $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
    $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
    $obj_pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
    $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);
    $obj_pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);
    $obj_pdf->AddPage();
    ob_start();

    $this->view('printconsignment');

    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content, true, false, true, false, '');
    $obj_pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'I');
```

In the view, as you can see, I have loaded the view like:

```php
$this->view('printconsignment');
```

As you can see, but however it’s displaying like below:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Pdf is rendering properly. You need seperate css for pdf and you have to define the size of the page